# Removing path-dependency from type check in Scala

Tags: scala, types, path-dependent-type

Say we have these nested classes and an instantiation of `A`:

```
class A {
  case object B
  case class C(c: Int)
}
val a1 = new A()
```

Now I can check that `a1.B` is an instance of `a1.B.type` but how can I check that the type of `a1.B` is an instance of *any* `A#B.type` because the compiler won’t accept that syntax.

```
a1.B.isInstanceOf[a1.B.type]
res: Boolean = true

a1.B.isInstanceOf[A#B.type]
<console>:1: error: ']' expected but '.' found.
a1.B.isInstanceOf[A#B.type]
                     ^
```

For the case class it seems to work without problems:

```
a1.C(0).isInstanceOf[a1.C]
res: Boolean = true

a1.C(0).isInstanceOf[A#C]
res: Boolean = true
```

Follow-up question: When I have

```
val a1 = new A()
val a2 = new A()
```

is there a function that does an equality check without taking path-dependency into account? Eg. it should return `true` when comparing `a1.B` and `a2.B`. For example:

```
a1.B =#= a2.B
true

a1.C(0) =#= a2.C(0)
true

a1.C(0) =#= a2.C(1)
false
```

**Edit**: For clarification: Just introducing a common trait for `B` is not enough as I want to bet able to distinguish between case objects:

```
class A {
    trait BB
    case object B1 extends BB
    case object B2 extends BB
}
val a1 = new A
val a2 = new A

a1.B1 =#= a2.B1 // should be true
a1.B2 =#= a2.B2 // should be true
a1.B1 =#= a1.B2 // should be false
a1.B1 =#= a2.B2 // should be false
```

Now, the `.hashCode` (or `.##`) method seems to solve the problem:

```
a1.B1.## == a2.B1.## // true
a1.B1.## == a2.B2.## // false
```

but maybe there is a more elegant solution (I’d also like to be able to use `a1.B1` in a pattern match for example).

Comment: Are you looking for a runtime (ie. post erasure) test?

Comment: I solved my problem by moving the `case object` out of the outer class so it is more a of a general question right now. I guess for the runtime value equality check one could work around by comparing the `hashCode` if there is no better way.

Comment: Do you want just the check to be ture or should `a1.C(0) == a2.C(0)`? If it should be use `final case class`

Comment: @NabilA. Interesting, but I also get an unchecked warning. And what would I do about the `case object`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use full form for expressing existential types.

Here your example:

```
class A {
  case object B1
  case object B2
  case class C(c: Int)
}
val a1 = new A()
```

I've added another case object to demonstrate that they could be distinguished and so I have not write an obscure equivalent for `AnyRef`

```
type AB1 = a.B1.type forSome {val a : A}
type AB2 = a.B2.type forSome {val a : A}

scala> a1.B1.isInstanceOf[AB1]
res0: Boolean = true

scala> a1.B1.isInstanceOf[AB2]
res1: Boolean = false
```

I've introduced type aliases `AB1` and `AB2` for convenience. But that types may be inlined into `isInstanceOf` if there is a need.

Answer (score 1):

I think `a1.B.isInstanceOf[A#B.type]` is syntacticly wrong. There is no `.type`

How about using a inner trait

```
 class A{
    trait BTrait
    object B extends BTrait
  }

    val a1 = new A
    a1.B.isInstanceOf[A#BTrait] // this is true
```

if you want your inner instances to be equal independent of the outer instance,

```
a1.C(0) == a2.C(0)
```

is ture if you declare `C` as

```
final case class C()
```

this does not work for `object`s

Comment: My problem is that I have `object B1 extends BTrait; object B2 extends BTrait; ...`. Just checking for `A#BTrait` is not enough.

Comment: `object B1 extends BTrait; object B2 extends BTrait;` is your choise. Use `object B1 extends BTrait1; object B2 extends BTrait2;` and if you need common stuff add a `with CommonStuffTrait` to both. `BTrait`should be for type check only.

Comment: Ah, makes sense. But still there is already the singleton type of the case object. Why can’t I just use it.

Comment: I am not sure what the complier does, but I think it is an instance singleton. So it is a local not global singleton. That would explain the seen behavior and would be logical, because you define it local as well.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is purely a syntax thing but the following seems to solve it:

```
class A {
  case object B
  type BType = B.type
  case class C(c: Int)
}
val a1 = new A()
val a2 = new A()

a1.B.isInstanceOf[a1.B.type]
res: Boolean = true

a1.B.isInstanceOf[A#BType]
res: Boolean = true
```

And then I can kill the (2.11) compiler with

```
a1.B match {
  case _: A#BType => println("ABC")
}

> error: scala.MatchError: (?_1.type#B.type,a1.B.type) (of class scala.Tuple2)
```

In dotty it works though and interestingly enough `a1.B.type` and `a1.BType` are different:

```
List(a1, a2) foreach { a =>
  a.B match {
    case _: a1.B.type => println("Matches a1")
    case _: a2.B.type => println("Matches a2")
    case _: A#BType => println("Matches a1 and a2")
    case _: a1.BType => println("Matches a1 and a2")
    case _: a2.BType => println("Matches a1 and a2")
    case x => println(x)
  }
}
```